# How to override hashCode and equals methods in serialized object?

Tags: java, oracle-coherence

I am using a `NamedCache.get(cacheKey)` and `NamedCache.put(cacheKey, cacheValue)` and overriding `hashCode` and `equals` method in a `cacheKey` object, also making the `cacheKey` object Serializable. But the `hashCode` and `equals` method isn't getting called.

Why is this happening?

I am posting a sample code for the above question

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.tangosol.net.CacheFactory;
import com.tangosol.net.NamedCache;

class HelloEx implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6280029994647038136L;
    String str  = "HelloEx" ; 

    HelloEx(String s){
        str = s ; 
    }


    public int hashCode() {
        System.out.println("Inside HashCode");
        return 1;

    }


    public boolean equals(Object  o) {
        HelloEx s = (HelloEx)o ;
        if(str.equals(s.str)){
            System.out.println("Both are equal");
            return true; 
        }
        return false;
    }


}


public class HashSetEg {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HelloEx hEx4 = new HelloEx("Four");
        HelloEx hEx5 = new HelloEx("Five");
        HelloEx hEx6 = new HelloEx("Six");

        Map hp = new HashMap();
        hp.put(hEx4,hEx4); 
        hp.put(hEx5,hEx5);
        hp.put(hEx6,hEx6);
        hp.put(hEx6,hEx6);
        System.out.println("Test");
        hp.get(hEx6);
        hp.put(new String("aa"),new String("aa"));
        System.out.println("Test");
        //System.out.println("HashSet " +  hp  );


            NamedCache aggCache  = CacheFactory.getCache("MyCache");
        aggCache.put(hEx4,hEx4);
        aggCache.put(hEx6,hEx6);
        aggCache.put(hEx6,hEx6);
        System.out.println("End");
    }
}
```

The output for the above code is:

Inside HashCode

Inside HashCode

Inside HashCode

Inside HashCode

Test

Inside HashCode

Test

End

This code is using oracle coherence technology.So **NamedCache** is an interface inside **coherence.jar** which is used to hold the reference of created cache on coherence server which will be used by application and "**CacheFactory.getCache("MyCache")**" is used to create a cache on coherence server with name MyCache and in this cache we store key-value pairs just like we store data in HashMap

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: I am afraid i can't post the actual code here.As it is on my clients VM(not accessable from here).

Comment: you most certainly can. Create an [mcve](/help/mcve) and paste that in (making sure it really is an mcve). The important thing is that you put in the effort to clearly explain what you're doing, which in this case pretty much *has* to include code, even if it's not literally the code you have - as long as it exhibits the same problem that you need to solve after reducing.

Comment: What is a `NameCache`? What is your serializable cache key object? What code are you using to establish this improbable claim? Not a real question.

Comment: A Map will call hashCode and equals, if your code is not calling these methods, either NamedCache is not a Map, or you are doing something wrongly.

Comment: I have added the code and also added few statements to explain few things. Please let me know if you need more information than this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand from [this](http://blackbeanbag.net/wp/2010/06/06/coherence-key-howto/) article, `NamedCache` does not call `hashCode` when you call `put`.

And, according to the article, you have to pay attention on how `hashCode` and `equals` are implemented.

Comment: I am sorry, but this didn't help. I didn't got your second line

Comment: @RaJnish, did you read the article? All serializable (non transient) fields in the key class must be used in the equals implementation. And hashCode is not called on put, and you test shows exactly that

Comment: No can you please provide me the link of that article

Comment: The link is in the answer (try clicking the word 'this' ).  Just in case you still can't find it: http://blackbeanbag.net/wp/2010/06/06/coherence-key-howto/